# CassiniDev 64bit Continuous Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, 64-bit, cassini-dev

I recently started using CassiniDev to run my WatiN tests on our CI servers. I when I build and test to our two 32 bit machines I have no problem running my tests. However when I build and test on our 64bit machine, I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CassiniDev4-lib, Version=4.0.1.7, 
Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=f7f6e0b4240c7c27' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

which I have come to find out is due to conflicts with the 64bit environment. On my local machine, which is 64bit I have no problem setting the platform target to x86 and my tests running like a dream. However, if I change my release configuration to target x86 and deploy to our 64bit machine, I still get the same error. Does anyone know of a work around for this? Some way that I could be able to build and test on both 32 and 64bit machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer this in case other people run into the same issue I've been having. What I ended up doing was creating a new configuration in Visual Studio called WatiN, in that I set all my projects to x86. On my CI server I build and run my WatiN tests separately from everything else using the WatiN configuration.